# c# unit testing visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm new to c# and programming in general. Need to write some unit testing. Want to write some for this class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using teamcanada.Models;
using System.Configuration;
using teamcanada.ingestion;

/* This class writes the parsed CSV data into the database */

namespace teamcanada.dal
{
    public class csvParseDAL
    {
        protected torontoDB db = new torontoDB();

        /* if the database is empty, then do not continue with the CSV parsing */

        public csvParseDAL()
        {
            if ((db.ElectionResults.ToList().Count() == 0) && (db.ElectionContributions.ToList().Count() == 0))
            {
                insertcsv();
            }
        }

        /* Start CSV parsing  */

        public void insertcsv()
        {
            List<Results> results = null;
            List<Contributions> contributions = null;

            LoadCSV import = new LoadCSV();

            results = import.loadResults();

            foreach (Results r in results)
            {
                db.ElectionResults.Add(r);
            }

            contributions = import.loadContributions();

            foreach (Contributions r in contributions)
            {

                db.ElectionContributions.Add(r);
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

D

Comment: You're not after a unit test, you're after an integration test (entity framework can be assumed to work properly)

Answer (score 2):

Generally what you'll want to do is to use the `Assert` class to compare expected and actual values. The actual values are usually return values of methods. In your case, I would recommend testing the return values of `import.loadResults();` and `import.loadContributions();` to make sure they return what you expect.

I see you use EF which is not something you need to unit test, that has already been done by Microsoft. If you need to you can use integration tests, where the tests have access to the database and check whether proper values have been inserted.

It is hard to give more specific advice, just create a Test Project in Visual Studio, play a round a bit and than maybe try asking more specific questions. You can use this [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/kgayda/unit-testing-in-visual-studio-2010) to understanding the basics of unit testing.

Comment: No problem, if it answers your question, you can mark it as an answer ;-)